# How to get nested DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get nested DOM.

I want to get the nested DOM by Jquery.

For example.

```
<div id="red">
  <div id="member">A</div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div id="member">B</div>
</div>
<div id="yellow">
  <div id="member">C</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to get the each memver id like, `yellow.member`

I want to do like this.

```
$("#yellow.member").removeClass("myclass");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nested dom"? The content inside of the children of the top elements?

Comment: Well, `id` is supposed to be unique, you know...

Comment: :/ repeated ids are a big no-no. Use classes and give it a space.

Comment: [RTFM](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wanted to access the child element of `#yellow` was real close to be correct.

```
$("#yellow .member").removeClass("myclass");
```

Notice the added space. The space means to look for another matching element in the descendant tree of the element matched by the previous selector.

Now it's your markup that is wrong. You just cannot use the same `id` more than once. The concept of `id` comes from long before the computer age... An "*identification*" is unique per definition!

Here is how your markup should look like... in a working example where the interval is just for fun:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $("#yellow .member").toggleClass("myclass");
  },1000);
});
```

```css
.myclass{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="red">
  <div class="member">A</div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div class="member">B</div>
</div>
<div id="yellow">
  <div class="member">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It helps me quite a lot. It makes you all confuse that I use `id` instead of `class` at the first time. Sorry for that. However I understand and be able to control DOM now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nested selectors with jQuery:

```
$('#yellow #member').removeClass('myclass');
```

Removes `.myclass` from the `#member` element inside `#yellow`.

Also, your HTML isn't valid. You can use an ID only once per document, so change all `<div id="member"> ... </div>` to `<div class="member"> ... </div>`. Then the selector passed to jQuery changes to

```
$('#yellow .member')
```

Answer (score -2):

What you're after is the `.find()` method.

```
$("#yellow").find('#member').removeClass("myclass");
```

Or `children()`

```
$("#yellow").children('#member').removeClass("myclass");
```

or

```
$('#yellow>#member'),removeClass("myClass");
```

EDIT: Also don't have duplicate id's. Use `class` attribute instead.

Comment: Yeah your right - didn't look at the rest of the html as they only specified '#yellow' child. Have amended @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: The edit doesn't make your answer much clearer... And there is another thing: a coma where a dot should be.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette If he wants me to review all of his code mate he can post on code review.

Comment: Code Review is for working and complete code... Not for question like this.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette fair point.. but my reasoning still stands. If someone asks a question on a specific subject I'll answer that question. Not disect each line of code they've posted. Especially when it's a trivial question like this

Comment: It was obviously not that *"trivial"* for OP... And since the access to a child element using a duplicate id is the main question, in my opinion, It has to be addressed